# How to search for the words in directory and write the output in other file which should have filename followed by testcases found in that file

Tags: linux, shell

```
for i in `cat /auto/qalogs/out.txt` ; do echo $i; grep -ril $i /auto/tools/; done > /auto/qalogs/out1.txt
```

I have a file(/auto/qalogs/out.txt) with testcase name only in each line. I need to search each testcase present in file in the given directory and output should be filename and testcases found on that file.

**Output of file should be like following :  Format can be any, but should have filename and testcases found in that file.**

filename1: list of testcases found in the file

filename2: list of testcases found in the file

example :

/auto/tools/file/file1.rb : tc1, tc2, tc3
/auto/tools/file/file2.rb : tc4, tc5, tc6

**getting output as following:**

tc1

/auto/tools/file/file1.rb

tc3

/auto/tools/file/file2.rb

tc2

/auto/tools/file/file1.rb

Please let me know if any details are required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand of your question, this should give you a rough idea of an approach - it is not the most efficient in the world, but it should be fairly easy to understand and adapt to your needs:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Make bash array of all filenames to look in and all test cases to look for
files=( $(find . -type f) )
cases=( $(cat testcases.txt) )

printf "################################################################################\n"
printf "Looking in these files:\n"
printf "%s\n"  "${files[@]}"
printf "################################################################################\n"
printf "\n"
printf "################################################################################\n"
printf "For these cases\n"
printf "%s\n" "${cases[@]}"
printf "################################################################################\n"
printf "\n"

# Look through all files in array "files"
for f in "${files[@]}" ; do
   # Clear out the results for this file, so we know if we found any cases
   res=""
   # Check if this file contains each case
   for c in "${cases[@]}" ; do
      if grep -q -m1 -w "$c" "$f" ; then
         # If it does, append this case to our result string "res"
         res="$res $c"
      fi
   done
   # If we found any test cases, print the filenames and the cases we found
   if [ ! -z "$res" ]  ; then
      echo "$f: $res"
   fi
done
```